# CasperJS not finding element by class when loaded via ajax

Tags: ajax, download, phantomjs, casperjs

I used several methods of attack attempting to get Casper to see the element in question, which gets loaded via a 2nd GET request that returns a bunch of json to get loaded into the page's DOM.

The thing is `this.waitForResource(url,....)` works fine executing the success callback after about 2 seconds (I have a timeout of 20 set).

I then tried first `this.click('.class-name')` inside followed by `this.evaluate(function(){document.getElementsByClassName('.class-name')[0].click()});`

Click via casperJS returns `CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: .class-name` while I'm not sure what the DOM action does - my `this.on('resource.received',....)` call immediately after doesn't capture anything so I assume it also had no effect either. DOM code seems to fail silently in Casper sometimes.

What can be done to select elements and click them to download files only after they are loaded into the DOM via ajax?

Is there a better library than CasperJS for this?

Answer (score 0):

Casper has [waitForSelector](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector) and [waitFor](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfor) methods that will suit your need.

`waitFor` will wait until provided function returns true

`waitForSelector` will wait until provided selector is in DOM, so I guess this is the one you want to use.

Additionaly there is [waitUntilVisible](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waituntilvisible) which wait until an element is visible on screen